# Can I force a page in history to be removed?

Tags: javascript, forms, back

Re editing... this question has NOT been answered before!

I had understood that changing the contents of a current page with window.location replaced the cached version of the original page ( from the "last" history), so that you really couldn't go back with the browser BACK button. I had even seen this posted as a solution to preventing a malicious visitor from using the BACK button to to re-submit a mail form many times. But it is NOT workable because in the case of a mail form, the BACK button will just take the user back to the pre-POST version of the page.

So, I can use javascript to reset the form, disable the SUBMIT button, change to another page after success, or do whatever I want to the page. But its all for nothing if a simple click of the BACK button followed by SUBMIT causes the form to post again with just 2 clicks.

I know there are a lot of solutions to preventing malicious form resubmissions I can try, but I've had trouble getting them to work, and so I'd just like to know if removing the last history is a dead end. If there is a way, and it is pretty cross browser friendly, then I can just make it part of my scripted actions once my form is successfully processed, and my "thank you" page displays. Basically I'd want my "thank you" page's 'onload' event to either erase the last history, or in a browser compatible way disable the BACK button!

For what its worth, I've included code from simple test I've been working with. You can put some junk in the fields and hit submit. The vars are cleared in the PHP, the form fields are force cleared in javascript, and a new 'location' is invoked. Unfortunately, hitting BACK button will take you back to the "pre-posted" form, with all the strings you added still intact.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Form Behavior Test</title>  
</head>


<!--
<?php

 $name = $email = $comments = "";
 $formDone = false;

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) 
   {
    $formDone = true;
    $name = $email = $comments = "";

   }
 ?>
-->

<body > 
 <table border="1"><tr><td style ="text-align:right;" width=100%> 
<form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 

Name:  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"value="<?php echo $email;?>"><br>
<br>
<div align="center"> ---- <span class="error">*</span> Message ---- <br>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" wrap="physical" cols="40" rows="10"  ><?php echo $comments;?></textarea>
</div>

<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form> 
</td></tr></table>


<script language="JavaScript"> 
if (<? echo ($formDone == true) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>)
 {
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("comments").value = "";
    document.getElementById("submit").value="Disabled";
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;

        // substitute with a thank you page
    window.location = "http://google.com";

 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Comment: This is not a duplicate from that question. The other question is only about PHP, this one is about JAVASCRIPT. Please read carefully before marking as duplicate.

Comment: @taxicala Agreed (and voted to reopen), but duplicate submission prevention *must* be implemented server-side. Anything client-side is just for a better UX when the prevention is triggered.

Comment: Randy - the topic is open again, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

After searching pretty exhaustively, I don't believe there is any way to remove a page from history, except on the very latest browsers that support newer HTML-5 history methods. I'm still open to solutions but at this point I think the easiest thing will be for me to set a cookie anytime a successful email is processed by my PHP code. Then, I can also make the PHP or a javascript snippet look for the cookie and if found, I can take all kinds of actions... wipe out all filled in fields (as they would be if the BACK button is pressed), block the email, politely inform the user that he/she must wait (until my cookie expires) to send another email though the form, etc.

I didn't want to do this originally because the BACK button doesn't actually re-load the page, it just displays it. If there were a universal browser compatible way to make pages reached by back buttons actually re-load, this would never have been a problem to begin with. So even with a cookie, my defensive actions couldn't activate until the SUBMIT button is pushed. I guess I can live with that. Also, even today, some people are paranoid about cookies and turn them off. But if I want to be adamant about it, I can just detect when I can't set a cookie, and inform the user that cookies are required to use my email form. If that's too big a deal, oh well!

Thanks to those that contributed. The fact is, the LACK of answers is really a very useful answer sometimes. When I post on any stackoverflow forum and don't get any answers pretty quickly, its a good red-flag that things are going to get convoluted really fast if I don't consider an alternate approach! :-)